# Is there any way to create or simulate a frugal installation of Ubuntu/Lubuntu on a usb flash drive?

Tags: usb, lubuntu

I've created a FULL installation of Ubuntu 15.10 on a USB stick that runs fine, except the fact that I don't have USB 3.0 port and it's extremely slow as expected.

Is there any way to make a frugal installation (like puppy Linux does) of Ubuntu (or Lubuntu since it's less demanding in RAM) or to force the fully installed version to preload, during boot, the mostly often used parts of it to RAM, in order to enhance the performance?

I suppose that what's slowing down the system the most are the parts that are often read and written, so I guess I'm looking for a way to use a part of RAM as a virtual disk for this purpose.

I'm very aware of the fact that I may be just daydreaming, since all the googling for this didn't return any results more recent than 2008, so maybe this scenario is abandoned by the developers.
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more answers

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ubuntu-toram-how-to-make-ubuntu-boot-to-ram/

[Customizing Ubuntu to run from RAM only, within GRUB options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275795/customizing-ubuntu-to-run-from-ram-only-within-grub-options)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258753/how-to-make-ubuntu-use-more-ram-to-cache-a-specific-set-of-binaries)

There is a guide of how to do exactly what I ask but it's quite old and valid for 14.10 version. So i have to try it.

And [here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed) i found how to decrease swapping and how to make files stay in the RAM cache longer, which both help.